# how to get value of a button other than using 'by id' convention?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the value of a button when it is clicked? What I know is by id as in the code below. Is there any other method?

```
<button type="buton" id="a" value="<?php echo $re[0]; ?>"  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showalert()">Start</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showalert(){
   var sub = document.getElementById("a").value;
   alert(sub);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="buton" id="a" value="<?php echo $re[0]; ?>"  
        class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showalert(this)">Start</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showalert(obj){
   alert(obj.value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using classname

```
getElementsByClassName()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors of jQuery.

Look in the Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

to get the Value just:

```
$("yourClassOrID").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many other option

You can use these as well

```
getElementByAttribute 

getElementsByClassName
```

In `getElementsByClassName` you have to provide class name which value you want to get.
Where as in `getElementByAttribute` you can provide any attribute.You can also provide your custom created attribute as well.

Comment: getting value by class name or attribute. I snot according to my situation. I was having a php while loop; creating many buttons at a time. Which was making same class and id for every button. But i was echoing different. values in every button. therefore I accepted @Harsh Makani answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
where selectors:id not matching your required id,class,html element

```
document.querySelector(selectors);
```

in case if you can use jquery

```
$( "button " ).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this. Using jquery.

```js
alert($("button")[0].value+"\n"+$("button")[1].value+"\n"+$("button")[2].value);

//with the help of javascript

function getValue(obj) {
  alert(obj.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="b1" value="first" onclick="getValue(this);">a</button>
    <button value="second" onclick="getValue(this);">b</button>
    <button value="third" onclick="getValue(this);">c</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Value will not get displayed.Try the snippet.**

Comment: This is a bad answer, it is possible to define a "value" attribute for a button. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button or http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: you can not give it like this. You have to put <button >b1</button>  to print the value. You can not put it inside value attribute.

Comment: It looks much better :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get value by another functions by using jQuery:

1. by id =>`$("#id").val();`
2. by class => `$(".class").val();`
3. by element => `$("element-name").val();`
   4.you can also get value of  any attribute by `$("any-of-above selectors").attr("attribute-name");`

Answer (score 0):

The question is: how to show the value of a button, when it was clicked.

The easiest way is to send the element as a parameter of a function with the `this` keyword. Like this:

```
<script>
function showText(element){
    alert(element.value);
}
</script>

<button onClick="showText(this)" value="Test1">Test1</button>
<button onClick="showText(this)" value="Test2">Test2</button>
```

With this code, you should see two buttons with the texts "Test1" and "Test2", and if you click on one of them you should get an alert box with the correct caption of the clicked button.